# Hibernate view mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, view, orm, mapping

I got two classes. A class named person and a class named group. Now I created a view linking these classes and created a class with an *@Immutual* annotation.

**View result**

```
| person_id | group_id |
| ----------|----------|
|     1     |     2    |
|     2     |     2    |
|     3     |     4    |
|    ...    |    ...   |
```

**Class PersonGroup**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_group")
@Immutable
public class PersonGroup {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Person person;

    @Column
    private Group group;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.person;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return this.group;
    }
}
```

Now i want to map *PersonGroup* to *Person* and *Group*. Like this:

**Class Person**

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    ...

    private PersonGroup group;

    ...

}
```

**Class Group**

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    ...

    private Set<PersonGroup> person;

    ...

}
```

Is that possible? If yes, which annotations should I use? I tried a lot and nothing worked for me.

Regards,
Xy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to use `PersonGroup` in the `Person` Model then u have to use `@Embeddable` annotations to embed a value type object into our Entity class.
   Like This :-

   ```
   @Entity
   @Embeddable
   @Table(name = "person_group")
   @Immutable
   public class PersonGroup {
   .....
   ```

   then add anotation @Embedded to the `Person` Class.
   Like this :-

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Person {

       ...
       @Embedded
       private PersonGroup group;
   ```
2. If you want to use the `PersonGroup` meodel in `Group`Model Then use the @ElementCollection Annotationin Group Class as Below

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Person {

       ...
       @ElementCollection
       private Set<PersonGroup> person;
   ```

Please refer to the below tutorial.

[Doc1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2abcy0Q1a0&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=10) and [Doc2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hofWx5_ZN9c&index=12&list=PL4AFF701184976B25)

Comment: Thank you so far. I tried to implement it that way, but unfortunately I have to work on Hibernate 3. I found an equivalent annotation for _@ElementCollection_ called _@CollectionOfElements_. Anyway, now I get an exception: `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [person] not found on xx.xxx.xxx.entity.Person`. I am a little confused why Hibernate tries to find a field called _person_ in class _Person_.

Comment: please refer to the below document.http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements